# Class not found - Laravel

Tags: laravel-8

Having issues with my Laravel application when I put it online. Locally, everything is working but now I'm having this error saying that the `Class 'App\Models\Island' not found.`  I think I'm following the rules with letter sensitivity here, but I am not so sure what is the problem.

```
namespace App\Providers;
use App\Models\Status;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Infrastructure;
use App\Models\Island;
use App\Models\Foreman;
use App\Models\Designer;
use App\Models\Engineer;
use App\Models\Type;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use View;
```

Futher down the script, line 57 is also highlighted as part of the error message.

```
    /**
     * Infrastructure
     */
    View::composer(['infrastructures.fields'], function ($view) {
        $islandItems = Island::pluck('island_name','id')->toArray(); // line 57
        $view->with('islandItems', $islandItems);
    });
```

Comment: If you are developing on Windows, but using a non-windows server, check all uppercase/lowercase characters in your file names if they match the namespace. Most of the time the not matching names is the issue on non-windows systems.

Comment: Thanks @Daantje, yes, I'm using windows and everything is working as expected but stop working on our domain. I will try and play around with that.